# Noisy steering after pwr steering leak fixed

Tags: honda, noise, power-steering, odyssey

I had a power steering leak for six months in my 2007 Honda Odyssey. Fixed the leak, but now, when I turn corners, sometimes, I hear a creaking/crunching sound coming from under the car from the wheels when the windows are down. What could that be from?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Did you completely bleed the power steering lines? The reason they are usually noisy is due to air being in the system.

Comment: I had it done at a very reputable shop. They do all our repairs and are very competent, so my guess is that they did all that.

Comment: over time, I am noticing it lessening, now that you mention this...

Comment: My adult children who drive it occasionally, said it's harder to steer than their cars. And I notice that the tires sometimes feel like they are low in pressure because of the way it turns, but the pressure is perfect in the tires.

Comment: To bleed the system, jack the front of the vehicle up and suspend it on jack stands. With the engine running, turn the steering, lock to lock several times. It needs to be done with minimal strain on the steering mechanism.

Comment: I'd suspect if it's not a problem with the power steering job. Than it's an upper strut mount, spring or lower balljoint. If it were a power steering problem the pump would be making noise and you'd hear a whining sound. Creaking/crunching sounds more like the aforementioned parts.